# SSL Certificates - differences

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

How come the prices on SLL certificates are so drastically varied? GoDaddy and Namecheap for example have them starting at $9 and $49 respectively. Then Verisign has them starting at $1500!

What's the difference? That's a huge price difference.

I have an application where each user account is on it's own subdomain, and so I need a certificate that covers them all.

Thoughts, suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actual differences are:

- Price
- Support
- Level of Certificate Validation
- Who/what trusts the Root CA

Really, It all comes down to the Root CA (Certificate Authority).

Verisign's Root CA is trusted by pretty much every device and browser out there.

If you purchase a certificate from (say) GoDaddy, then it will probably be trusted by your major browsers and operating systems. However, if you need SSL certificates to work on a particular brand of set-top-box, or mobile device, then you need to find out what Root CA's they trust.

While the certificate from an untrusted Root CA will still be perfectly valid, the device (browser, gadget, whatever) has no way to verify that it's a legitimate certificate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the cost of an SSL cert generally comes down to things like encryption strength, issue time, update time, support, warranty, and things of that nature.

With regard to users on sub domains how about a wildcard ssl certificate from Comodo? Expensive but will cover your entire site in one hit. 
http://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-products/ssl/ssl-certificate-sgc-wildcard.html

**Edit** Found a comparison site http://www.whichssl.com/comparisons/index.html

Answer (score 1):

there are diffrent types of levels of ssl, meaning more verified = more money in short...

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the marketing.  A Godaddy cert will get you just as far as a Verisign one (I know, I've had both).

Comment: Personally, as an internet user I feel a little better when Verisign's stamp is on a website.  Nobody thinks about putting "Secured by GoDaddy" on their web pages. :)  But I admit, they do have good Super Bowl commercials.